# How to automatically clone <tr> when user finish fill up text input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have simple form with 2 textfield `Name` and `Phone` and can add new field when click `Add new` button. You can refer here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ruslyrossi/3J65U/1/) .

My problem is how to add new textfield without press `Add New` button? When user fill up `Text Input name` and `Text Input Phone` new row `<tr class="person">` will automatically added.

My second problem is I'm not sure how to write code for delete.

UPDATE : I also want to set maximum clone, can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "fill up" you mean "when the user enters as many characters as the Phone field allows" then you can add a `maxlength="10"` attribute to the input (setting the value as appropriate):

```
<input type="text" name="phone[]" id="phone" maxlength="10"/>
```

...and add a handler to the `keyup` event that checks whether the current value has reached the `maxlength`:

```
$('input[name="phone\[\]"]').keyup(function() {
    if (this===$('input[name="phone\[\]"]').last()[0]
        && this.value.length===+$(this).attr("maxlength")) {
        $("#add").click();
    }
});
```

Note that you probably only want to do this test if the user is typing in the last row, hence the first part of the `if` test above.

Also you probably want the newly cloned fields to be blank, so you can do this within your add function:

```
$('#mytable tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#mytable tbody>tr:last')
                           .find("input").val("");
```

To set a maximum number of rows you can put a test in your add function:

```
$("#add").click(function() {
    var $lastRow = $('#mytable tbody>tr:last');
    if ($lastRow.index() < 10) { // set maximum rows here
        $lastRow.clone(true).insertAfter($lastRow).find("input").val("");
    }
    return false;
});
```

Note also that you don't need to give those inputs an `id` attribute, but if you do you shouldn't copy it when you clone because `id` should be unique.

For a delete function, add a delete button to each row:

```
<td><input type="button" class="deleteRow" value="Delete"/></td>
```

...and then:

```
$("#mytable").on("click","input.deleteRow", function(){
    if ($("#mytable tr").length > 2) // don't delete the last row
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3J65U/15/

Comment: this is what im looking for, you know how to set maximum clone and add delete function?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show a method to enforce a maximum number of rows and to delete rows.

Comment: Why you all are using `name='something[]'` what `[]` does?

Comment: @PedroGabriel - I've used it in my answer because the OP had it in the original markup. Client-side it does nothing, the `[]` part is simply a part of the name, but some server-side technologies (e.g., PHP) use it as an indication that that request parameter should be an array.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it on `blur` as well as the add new button. Also be careful with duplicated id's, use classes instead:

```
<tr class="person">
  <td><input type="text" name="name[]" class="name" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="phone[]" class="phone" /></td>
</tr>
```

Then in jQuery:

```
$('.phone').blur(function() {
  var ppl = $('.person').length;
  if ( this.value && ppl < 5 ) { // Max 5 people
    $(this).closest('tr').clone(true)
      .insertAfter('#mytable tr:last')
      .find('input').val('').first().focus();
    $(this).off('blur');
  }
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/YEBQt/ (tab from input to input)

Comment: you know how to set maximum clone ? and delete again(with button)

Comment: Check  my edit for the maximum clone solution. I'll leave the delete solution up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I would expand on enclares - I would use `.blur()` for each textbox , and each time check and make sure each value is not "" - that would make sure both are filled

Then in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".phone").blur(function() {
      var phonetxt = $('.phone'.val();
      var nametxt = $('.name').val();
      if ( phonetxt != "" && nametxt != "" ){
        $(this).closest('tr').clone(true)
            .insertAfter('#mytable tr:last')
            .find('input').val('').first().focus();
    });
}

 $(".name").blur(function() {
    var phonetxt = $('.phone'.val();
    var nametxt = $('.name').val();
    if ( phonetxt != "" && nametxt != "" ){
        $(this).closest('tr').clone(true)
            .insertAfter('#mytable tr:last')
            .find('input').val('').first().focus();
    });
  }
});​
```